# Не работает height. CSS/HTML. Зато работает Width

Tags: html, css, веб-сайт

Я разрабатываю свой сайт. Мне необходимо сделать так что-бы картинка была большая. Разумеется я нашёл только один способ - увеличение по диагонали. 100 ширины 100 высоты. Казалось бы я прав! Но... оказалось что у меня не работает свойство  `height`! Но, почему-то работает  `width`.
[image: width="100" height="5000width="400" height="5000""]

Что мне делать?
HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>OverWalk</title>
   <meta name="descritpion" content="Приватный сервер Minecraft">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="ico/favicon.ico" type="image x/icon">
</head>

<body>
   <header>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="logo">
               <img src="img/logo.png" alt="OverWalk">
           </div>
           <nav>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#header">Главная</a></li>
                   <li><a href="https://vk.com/overwalk">Контакты</a></li>
                   <li><a href="http://mc.overwalk.ru:8123">Карта</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Проходка</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">F.A.Q.</a></li>
                   <li><a href="https://www.donationalerts.com/r/overwalk"><strong>Поддержать</strong></a></li>
       </div>
       </ul>
       </nav>
       </div>

   </header>
   <section class="banner">
       <div class="container">
           <h1>Играйте в ванильный<br> Minecraft так, как хотите вы</h1>
           <h2>
               OverWalk — это классический сервер c отбором<br> игроков по анкетам и проходкам. Без привата,<br> привелегий и только с дружелюбными к ваниле<br> плагинами. Почти как MineShield. </h2>
           <a href="#header"> <button class="Main_button" margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;margin-top:22%;margin-bottom:0%>Начать игру</button></a>

           </p>
       </div>
   </section>
   <main>
       <section class="text">
           <div class="container">
               <p class="text">Что такое приватный сервер?</p>
               <p class="textAnswerForServer">Это ванильный Minecraft, но с большим и активным<br> сообществом игроков, которые станут вашими друзьями. Без<br> привата, доната, и только с дружелюбными к ваниле плагинами.<br> Чтобы попасть на сервер нужно заполнить анкету или заплатить<br>                    за проходку. За гриферство мы баним, а пострадавшие<br> постройки восстанавливаем.<br>
               </p>
               <figure class="fig">
                   <img src="img/First.png" height="50%" width="10%" alt="Похоже, что у вас включен режим турбо, либо плохой интернет.">
                   <figcaption>
                       Лавочка продавца
                   </figcaption>
               </figure>
           </div>
       </section>
       <section class="banner2">
           <div class="container">

           </div>
       </section>
   </main>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: grreg;
    src: url(../fonts/Gilroy-Regular.woff) format("woff");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: grsb;
    src: url(../fonts/Gilroy-SemiBold.woff) format("woff");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: grb;
    src: url(/fonts/Gilroy-Bold.woff) format("woff")
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik+One&subset=latin,cyrillic);
.gradient-text {
    font-family: 'grsb', 'grreg';
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, orange 49%, purple 51%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: table;
    margin: 20px left;
    text-align: left;
}

html,
body,
.container {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(66, 76, 71);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

img {
    height: 50px;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

header .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Gilroy";
    color: rgb(137, 137, 137);
    line-height: 0.867;
}

nav li a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: unset;
    font-family: "Gilroy";
}

h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: grsb;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: grsb;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.h19 {
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: grsb;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.Main_button {
    background-color: orange;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: grsb;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 22px 0px 22px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 2cm;
    margin-left: -2.5cm;
}

.banner {
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    padding: 300px 100px 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    transform: translate(0 -50);
    margin-top: -2cm;
}

.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.whatIsServer {
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'grsb', 'grreg';
}

.text {
    font-family: 'grsb', 'grreg';
    font-size: 32px;
    background: white;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: table;
    margin: 20px left;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1;
}

.textAnswerForServer {
    font-family: 'grsb', 'grreg';
    font-size: 15px;
    background: white;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: table;
    margin: 20px left;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1;
}

.banner2 {
    background-image: url(../img/First.jpg);
    padding: 300px 100px 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    transform: translate(0 -50);
    margin-right: 4cm;
}

.LavDrive {
    max-width: auto;
    max-height: auto;
    min-height: auto;
    min-width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2.5cm;
    bottom: -1.5cm;
}

.okno {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #0000cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #0000cc;
}

.fig {
    display: block;
    /* Блочный элемент (для старых браузеров) */
    text-align: right;
    /* Выравнивание по центру */
    font-style: italic;
    /* Курсивное начертание */
    margin-top: 0;
    /* Отступ сверху */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* Отступ снизу */
    color: #666;
    /* Цвет подрисуночной подписи */
}

.First {
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Код покажите. Сейчас это будет гаданием на кофейной гуще.

Comment: За код спасибо. Дайте угадаю, говоря о картинке вы имеете в виду картинку в логотипе или картинку в теге `figure`? Если последнее, то у картинка инлайново указана высота как 50% и этот стиль имеет приоритет (перебивает стили, если они указаны в css-файле. Чтобы не приходилось гадать, эту информацию стоило сразу включить в ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Quazimorda   то есть мне просто нужно удалить информацию о вейте и хейте в хтмл, а самому задавать эти два параметра в css?

Comment: Да, если вы хотите, чтобы применялись стили из внешнего css-файла. Вообще, если вы задаёте стили одному и тому же селектору, то наивысший приоритет у стилей, заданных инлайново, то есть прямо в теге, затем у стилей, которые заданы в head данного файла и только потом внешний файл стилей. Если у вас есть внешний файл, старайтесь как можно реже задавать стили инлайново.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В стиле css указываешь
height:200px;(например)
width:400px;

Comment: Обычно при изменении width, height меняется пропорционально.

Comment: У вас в html заданы высота и ширина для картинки. В процентах. Они имеют приоритет перед внешним файлом css. Поэтому как не задавайте меняться не будет. Плюс высота и ширина в процентах берется от высоты и ширины блока где находится картинка.